# Cardview in the recyclerview overlaps the collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to create a recyclerview below a collapsing toolbar with cardviews inside the recyclerview.How to overcome the overlapping of cardview inflated inside the recyclerview. It overlaps the collapsing toolbar image .

xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        style="@style/fab"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        />




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

item inflated inside recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.co nbm/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:padding="6dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/cv">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.co nbm/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">




        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/li"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            app:siBorderWidth="6dp"
            app:siBorderColor="@color/secondary_text"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:text="Aayush Chaubey"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="app developer"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />




    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Take a look also, especially :**

https://github.com/liuguangqiang/AndroidDesignSupportSample

**And this layout:** https://github.com/liuguangqiang/AndroidDesignSupportSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml

Answer (score 1):

In your first layout file place recylerview bottom of AppBarLayout:

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
```

instead of:

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/image"
```